# Unable to resolve View using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf.I am creating a spring-boot app using thymeleaf in view part.

Please find below my pom.xml file[only the dependencies part]:

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>
 <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I have created an application.properties file in following location:**src/main/resources**

```
server.port = 8086
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```

Following is my Boot Application Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="<common package structure>")
public class AdvMain extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(AdvMain.class);
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AdvMain.class, args);
   }
}
```

I have a controller class as follows:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(path = "/info", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public String info(Model model) {
       model.addAttribute("message", "Thymeleaf");
       return "info";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
       return "index";
    }
 }
```

When I invoke the following url:

```
http://localhost:8086/AddViewer/home
```

**I am getting page not found error.**

Please find below my tomcat console log:

```
   Mapped "{[/home],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String <package_Structure>.HomeController.index()
   Mapped "{[/info],methods=[GET || POST]}" onto public java.lang.String <package_Structure>.HomeController.info(org.springframework.ui.Model)
   Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
   Tomcat started on port(s): 8086 (http)
   FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 29 ms
   No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/AddViewer/home] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Can anyone provide any suitable solution to this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem of thymeleaf. 
In your console message, you have two mappings, `/home` and `/info`.

```
Mapped "{[/home],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String <package_Structure>.HomeController.index()
Mapped "{[/info],methods=[GET || POST]}" onto public java.lang.String <package_Structure>.HomeController.info(org.springframework.ui.Model)
```

But you made a request `/AddViewer/home`. So, it does not matches with request mappings.

Request like this.

```
http://localhost:8086/home
```

Answer (score 0):

if you using thymeleaf put your view files in **src/main/resources/template** and no need to add these two line -

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```

Comment: already checked this not working same issue persist.Moreover as far as I know default location for view files is src/main/resources/template but it can be overridden using spring.thymeleaf.prefix/suffix tag,as I have done